# Why a critical point is a critical point

Tags: calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this function

$g(\textbf{x})= || \textbf{x}-\textbf{u}||^2 \cdot || \textbf{x}+\textbf{u}||^2$ for $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and where $\textbf{u}$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

and I'm already aware the critical points are at $\textbf{u}, -\textbf{u}$ and **0**.

Usually to prove these were actaully critical points I would just solve when the derivative is equal to $0$ but the question wants an analytical explanation and I'm unsure how I'm meant to write that since I'm so used to just doing the mathematical explanation.

Comment: Are $x,u$ really in $\mathbb R$ and not in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: sorry yes they are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I didnit read the question correctly

Comment: If that's all that it says regarding explanations then in this situation you should feel free to treat the expressions "analytical explanation" and "mathematical explanation" as synonyms, and do what comes naturally to you by solving when the derivative is equal to zero. I do see your comment to the second answer, so if that's what you really meant then your question should be edited to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I take the hypothesis below that $x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert$ stands for the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^n$. I also exclude the case $u=0$ which is simple to handle.*

The map $g$ is non-negative and smooth. As
$$g(u)=g(-u)=0$$ $u,-u$ are points where $g$ has a minimum and therefore those points are critical: a point where the derivative doesn't vanish can't be a local minimum.

We also have

$$\begin{aligned}g(x) &= (\Vert u \Vert^2 - 2 (x,u) +\Vert x \Vert^2)(\Vert u \Vert^2 + 2 (x,u) +\Vert x \Vert^2)\\
&=(\Vert u \Vert^2 +\Vert x \Vert^2)^2 - 4(x,u)^2
\end{aligned}.$$

Based on this equality, we can notice that:

1. If $x$ lies in the hyperplane orthogonal to $u$ and passing through $0$, $g$ has a minimum at $0$
2. And for $x = \lambda u$, we get $g(\lambda u) = \Vert u \Vert^4(1-\lambda^2)^2$. Which has a local maximum for $\lambda = 0$.

This proves that $x=0$ is also a critical point. A saddle point to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $u\ne 0$.
The gradient of $g$ is given as
$$
2\nabla g(x) = \|x-u\|^2 (x+u) + \|x+u\|^2(x-u).
$$
Then $\nabla g(x) =0$  only if $(\|x-u\|^2 + \|x+u\|^2)x$ is a multiple of $u$. Since $\|x-u\|^2 + \|x+u\|^2>0$ for all $x$ (here we need $U\ne 0$), $\nabla g(x) =0$ only if $x = tu$ for some $t\in \mathbb R$. The equation $\nabla g(tu)=0$ is a polynomial of third order in $t$. You found the roots $-1,0,+1$, and there can be no more roots or critical points.

Comment: In the question, it is mentioned to avoid using the derivative...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net no, it is not.